# Incomplete http response in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to get response from my office server. Response has minimum 50,000 lines. But I'm not getting complete response. I don't know where went wrong. Whether complete data not getting download or any other problem with my InputStream?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext httpcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(mUrl);
HttpResponse mResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpcontext);
InputStream mResponseStream = mResponse.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mResponseStream));
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
    Log.v("Response", line);
}
```

Required Response:

```
02-17 18:32:14.000: D/Lib(4121): Starts
02-17 18:32:14.010: D/Lib(4121): 12080964|~|1370.00
02-17 18:32:14.010: D/Lib(4121): 12083142|~|500.00
02-17 18:32:14.020: D/Lib(4121): 13051372|~|100.00
02-17 18:32:14.020: D/Lib(4121): 13040457|~|12.00
02-17 18:32:14.060: D/Lib(4121): 12010037|~|170.00
02-17 18:32:14.060: D/Lib(4121): .........
02-17 18:32:14.060: D/Lib(4121): Ends
```

Getting Response:

```
02-17 18:32:14.000: D/Lib(4121): Starts
02-17 18:32:14.010: D/Lib(4121): 12080964|~|1370.00
02-17 18:32:14.010: D/Lib(4121): 12083142|~|500.00
02-17 18:32:14.020: D/Lib(4121): 13051372|~|100.00
02-17 18:32:14.020: D/Lib(4121): 13040457|~|12.00
02-17 18:32:14.060: D/Lib(4121): 12010037|~|170.00
02-17 18:32:14.060: D/Lib(4121): .........
```

My response always starts with `Starts` keyword and ends with `Ends` keyword. Always i'm not get `Ends` keyword. Response getting stopped within line number 25,000 to 33,000. Thank You.

Comment: and what you get when you request this by hand or via other tool like curl? (btw: you should do GET request, not POST - you send nothing that requires POST)

Comment: try to give size to BufferedReader

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i'm sending data for authentication and i did not use curl.

Comment: @SathishKumar use curl and see what's the output there

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski sorry i don't know about curl,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I get string from response after that i convert that string response into `InputStream`, this process gives complete response. While I tried to get `InputStream` from  response it returns imcomplete data. Anyhow, I got complete response but till I don't know why I can not get complete response using `mResponse.getEntity().getContent()`.

My working code,

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext httpcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(mUrl);
HttpResponse mResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpcontext);
String responseString=EntityUtils.toString(mResponse.getEntity());
InputStream mResponseStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseString.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mResponseStream));
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
    Log.v("Response", line);
}
```