# Android InputStream stops returning after reading 64k string sent over the internet

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming, netty

We are using Netty on back end for handling sockets, and client-server communications is just sending strings over netty channel. When we try to send a string longer than 65536 bytes long (81188 in this particular case) from server to Android app the following happens, `BufferedReader.readLine()` in the app reads 65536 bytes and indeed returns the incomplete String, after that it reads `null` and no longer reads the input stream. Python client though works fine and after receiving 64k of data it continues reading without any issues. When I try to send the same data while running the back end on my laptop and the Android app on my home wifi everything works well and all 81188 bytes get buffered and successfully read and input stream continues to work.

Any suggestions what it may be?

The code for reading is quite basic:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
while (!socketClosed) {
    String incomingMessage = in.readLine();
    if (incomingMessage != null) {
        incomingMessagesHandler.handleMessage(incomingMessage, context);
    } else{
        System.out.println("socketClosed = true");
        socketClosed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the android code that reads the stream? Also any related `logcat` errors, stacktrace would be useful

Comment: Also check this answer if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871565/3635454

Comment: @pleft unfortunately there is no stacktrace since there is no error while reading

Comment: You should not send a string if you try to read a line.

Comment: Or you should not try to read lines if no lines are sent but only a big string.

Comment: @greenapps could you please elaborate? I have also tried reading and aggregating bytes instead of doing readLine() but faced the same issue. There are different sizes of strings being passed around in our app.